# How to remove jumbotron extra space?

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm fairly new to coding and building a simple personal website as a project for free code camp. I can't seem to get rid of the extra white space that jumbotron creates on the right side of my table of contents. I tried negative values in the padding, but it didn't work. Can anyone help with this?

[image]

**Code:**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-image: url("http://www.iamag.co/features/itsart/wp-
  content/uploads/2014/07/imperial-boy-16.jpg");
}
.jumbotron {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
#toc {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#toc li {
  background: url(dot.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
#toc a {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron"><h2><u>Table of Contents</u></h2>
  <ul id="toc">
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#links">Social Media Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chapter 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chapter 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chapter 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need that element to remain full-width, or only as long as your "table of contents"?

Comment: Just the width of the table of contents so the rest of the screen is more open to show the background.

Comment: Take a look at the *utility classes* you can use to set a specific element's *display property* -- > https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/ Or you could declare your own class with your own custom rules.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the problem you're experiencing comes from the `8px` of `margin` added to `body` by default. Simply overriding this manually should fix your problem:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This can be seen working here:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-image: url("http://www.iamag.co/features/itsart/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/imperial-boy-16.jpg");
  margin: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

#toc {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#toc li {
  background: url(dot.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#toc a {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h2><u>Table of Contents</u></h2>
  <ul id="toc">
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#links">Social Media Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chapter 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chapter 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chapter 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: For whatever reason this didn't change anything. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.jumbotron {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem although now the title and the table of contents are on the same row though I can probably fix them somehow.

Comment: For further assistance you may contact me.